# Access underlying projection functions in python basemap or cartopy

Tags: 3d, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I would like to use either basemap or cartopy to plot the orbits of satellites around the earth.  Both libraries offer the ability to plot the earth as seen from an observer in space (e.g. orthographic or Geostationary, etc.) and to plot something on the earth given a latitude and longitude.  Given this functionality it seems that the underlying projection functions that generate a point in the figure given the latitude and longitude should be callable where one could specify a different altitude (other than sea level).

Thus, shouldn't it be possible to use either basemap or cartopy to plot a satellite orbit given a longitude, latitude and altitude?

Note #1:  I know that the ground track of the satellite can be plotted but this ignores the altitude and I would like to see the altitude dependence.

Note #2:  I've seen that you can add Basemap to a Matplotlib 3D axes but this doesn't seem to work with "orthographic" projections.

Note #3  I'm looking for the ability to make something similar to [3D image of Earth with Satellite Trajectories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Ps4.jpg) using (latitude, longitude, altitude) coordinates

Comment: #3 is out of scope of map projection's targeted purposes.

Comment: I agree that it is out of the scope of the targeted purpose, however the mathematics suggests that this should be possible and I am curious if there is a way to access the underlying transformations.  I'm not asking for an extension to the library to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need map projection to get the required plot of satellites around the earth. Three-D plot can be used to create the globe, drape the earth image around it, then plot points above the globe surface.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
from matplotlib._png import read_png

# Use world image with shape (360 rows, 720 columns) 
pngfile = r"./eo_base_2020_clean_720x360.png"

fn = get_sample_data(pngfile, asfileobj=False)
img = read_png(fn)   # get array of color

# Some needed functions / constant
r = 5
pi = np.pi
cos = np.cos
sin = np.sin
sqrt = np.sqrt

# Prep values to match the image shape (360 rows, 720 columns)
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:pi:360j, 0:2*pi:720j]

# Parametric eq for a spherical globe
# phi=latitude; theta=longitude
x = r * sin(phi) * cos(theta)
y = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
z = r * cos(phi)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(9, 9)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', label='axes1')

# drape the image on the globe's surface
sp = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, \
                rstride=2, cstride=2, \
                facecolors=img)

# plot some points above/around the globe
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:pi:50j, 0:2*pi:50j]
r2 = 1.5*r
x = r2 * sin(phi) * cos(theta)
y = r2 * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
z = r2 * cos(phi) + 0.8* sin(sqrt(x**2 + y**2)) * cos(2*theta)
ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=1, color='red')

ax.set_axis_off()
ax.set_aspect(1)

plt.show()
```

[image: satellites]

> Map Projections are Coordinate Transformations

All map projections are sets of transformation functions from geoposition to a plane coordinate system. Practical implementation needs certain rules and scope to avoid misuse. My code above can be considered loosely 2 map projections in one place. The 1st globe use r=5 as the earth radius, and this projection is used to plot the bluemarble image's pixels on the projection plane. Another globe at the common position uses radius r2 = 1.5*r. It represents another projection that is used to plot the points that can be the orbiting earth satellites.

To implement 2 superimposed map projections on a single `axis` of `Cartopy` or `Basemap` is technically possible with some special coordinate transformation available in the plotting process.

Comment: Thanks!  This certainly gets to the spirit of what I was asking.