# 3D elevation on geographical map with python

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib-basemap, elevation

I am trying to display elevation/topography in 3D on a geographical map

I am currently displaying elevation with a colormap using the scatter function of matplolib over a geographical map created with the basemap package. I would like to visualize it in 3D with a shady effect or something similar.

Bellow is a simple example using data created randomly. The only constrain is to keep the 'ortho' look shown bellow. Any python package could be used.

Input data could either be a 1D arrays or 2D arrays.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

size = 1000

# data to plot
data = np.arange(size)*0.5/size

# coordinates
lat = np.random.uniform(low=65, high=90, size=(size,))
lon = np.random.uniform(low=-180, high=180, size=(size,))

f1, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,figsize=(9,8))

m = Basemap(projection='ortho',lat_0=70,lon_0=0,resolution='l',ax=ax) 
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25, zorder=0)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(90,-90,-5),  labels=[1,1,1,1],linewidth = 0.25, zorder=1)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,30.),labels=[1,1,1,1],latmax=85, linewidth = 0.25, zorder=1)
m.fillcontinents(color='dimgray',lake_color='grey', zorder=1)

x,y = m(lon,lat)
cmap='viridis'
m.scatter(x,y,c=data,s=10,cmap=cmap,vmin=0,vmax=0.5,zorder=3,alpha=1)

plt.show()
```

[image: Random 2D elevation in Arctic]

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Is this what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67737949/access-underlying-projection-functions-in-python-basemap-or-cartopy  ??

Comment: No, it's something similar, but I don't think that with the approach you propose you can zoom over the Arctic ocean. 
I would like to get something similar to that: https://twitter.com/ESA_EO/status/1395687109957242881

Comment: That is video clip.

Comment: Yes but only consider one frame in the clip. The idea being to reproduce the 3D volume look you can see on each map of the clip. Something simpler of course.

Comment: FYI `Is there a python package that enables to visualise or produce a 3D effect  ...` is considered off-topic on S/O. Don't be surprised if someone close this question.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip, I edited the question. I think that it's a interesting question for the community.